# Get the current logged user in the django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am making a blog website , which each user cannot post more than 3 blogs

so I wrote that in the form.py file so it can validate the number of blogs before submitting

this is the form code

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
blog=forms.CharField(label='',
            widget=forms.Textarea(
                    attrs={'placeholder': "Your blog",
                        "class": "form-control",
                        }
                ))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(BlogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data=super(BlogForm, self).clean()
    user=cleaned_data.get(self.request.user)
    if Blog.objects.filter(user=user).count()>=3:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You have exceeded limit.")

class Meta:
    model=Blog
    fields = ['user',
              'blog',
             'tags']
```

My Class Based View for the blog creation

```
class BlogCreateView(FormUserNeededMixin,CreateView):
form_class = BlogForm
template_name = 'blog/createview.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
form = BlogForm(user=request.user)
```

Expected Result : By the fourth blog submission of the same logged user , "You have exceeded limit." this error must appear

Actual :'BlogForm' object has no attribute 'request' this error appear

Comment: Post your forms code

Comment: I just posted it ... its BlogFrom class

Comment: Your question information is inclomplete. Also, remove "please help ASAP".. from question tag and do not include it with the question itself. Its obvious that you need help... you wouldn't have posted the question ;-) Questionformat: text top, code below. People don't like scrolling down to read what is needed. Prepare them in advance where to look at.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
blog=forms.CharField(label='',
            widget=forms.Textarea(
                    attrs={'placeholder': "Your blog",
                        "class": "form-control",
                        }
                ))
```

add this method to your Form Class

```
def __init__(self,user, *args, **kwargs):
        // do something with user
```

in view function

```
form_class = BlogForm
def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```

Comment: its class-based view function

Comment: post the view too

Comment: because I gave code for function based view. show the class based view.

Comment: done , kindly check the method I added to the form too

Comment: ok its okay now in the view , can you tell me please what to do if I want to prevent the user from submitting the fourth blog ? what to write under the __init__ function

Comment: that is your logic? what you want to check, and obviously that a different set of question you need to post again

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the request object to your form. if you are using method based views then do it like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = BlogForm(request.POST,request=request)
```

if you are using class based view, then override `get_form_kwargs()` method:

```
class SomeView(CreateView):

   def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
     form_kwargs = super(SomeView).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
     form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
     return form_kwargs
```

Then override the `BlogForm` to accept the request from view:

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        if request:
           self.request = request
        super(BlogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you should be able to access **request object** in `self.request`